# Trigger Ubuntu session logout from my own script

Tags: ubuntu, x11, dbus, display-manager

I want to write a Python script to run in Ubuntu session that can under certain conditions logout the user - think *screen time* management for kids :)

Can someone give me a pointer where to look, how is **logout** done in modern Linux desktops? I suspect it may have something to do with *dbus* but can't find any concrete way to do it. A pointer will be enough, I can figure out the rest :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt [this](https://superuser.com/questions/688720/how-do-i-auto-log-off-users-from-ubuntu) solution to something workable for you.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a "proper" solution - use `loginctl kill-session ...`. It can obviously be called from my python script too.